# Error on generated file for AsyncNotifierProvider `.family` Riverpod providers

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I wonder if I am overlooking something. When ever I try to generate the following via `riverpod_annotation` I'm getting the error below where it cannot find `Family` class. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

I've deleted and rebuilt the file multiple times and I'm not sure what I can change to make it work.

Here's the gist with both the controller and the generated controller logic

https://gist.github.com/Morzaram/7d75bcfed06ea7cce88a8b11c4fad223

```dart
import 'package:front_end/utils/pocketbase_provider.dart';
import 'package:pocketbase/pocketbase.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
part 'mangage_topic_voices_controller.g.dart';

@riverpod
class ManageTopicVoicesController extends _$ManageTopicVoicesController {
  List<String> _selectedVoices = [];
  bool mounted = true;

  get selectedVoices => _selectedVoices;
  @override
  FutureOr<void> build({required List<String> ids}) {
    ref.onDispose(() {
      mounted = false;
    });
    if (mounted) {
      _selectedVoices = ids;
    }
  }

  void addVoice(String id) {
    _selectedVoices = [..._selectedVoices, id];
  }

  void removeVoice(String id) {
    _selectedVoices = _selectedVoices.where((e) => e != id).toList();
  }

  Future<RecordModel> updateTopic({topicId, selectedVoices}) async {
    final res = await pb
        .collection('topics')
        .update(topicId, body: {"voices": selectedVoices});

    return res;
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is `Classes can only extend other classes. Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause.` and it's occuring on the first line of `Family<AsyncValue<void>>`

```dart
class ManageTopicVoicesControllerFamily extends Family<AsyncValue<void>> { 
  ManageTopicVoicesControllerFamily();

  ManageTopicVoicesControllerProvider call({
    required List<String> ids,
  }) {
    return ManageTopicVoicesControllerProvider(
      ids: ids,
    );
  }

  @override
  AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderImpl<ManageTopicVoicesController, void>
      getProviderOverride(
    covariant ManageTopicVoicesControllerProvider provider,
  ) {
    return call(
      ids: provider.ids,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<ProviderOrFamily>? get allTransitiveDependencies => null;

  @override
  List<ProviderOrFamily>? get dependencies => null;

  @override
  String? get name => r'manageTopicVoicesControllerProvider';
}
```

I know that the error is saying that the Family class doesn't exist, but I'm not sure if the error is due to me or not.

Can I not use family with this currently? I would love any help that I can get.

I'm new to dart, so apologies, and thank you in advance!

---

[Here's the gist with both files](https://gist.github.com/Morzaram/7d75bcfed06ea7cce88a8b11c4fad223)

Comment: Do you have the `part of ` earlier in the file?

Comment: Hey yes, here's the gist with both files
https://gist.github.com/Morzaram/7d75bcfed06ea7cce88a8b11c4fad223

Comment: It's possibly a regression of the newer version

Comment: @RémiRousselet I'm not sure what happened to cause it, but doing a `dart pub cache clean` did the trick